# how to check is python command is using some external api over internet internally

Tags: python

I am using a open source python package , how to verify that this package is not hitting some external api over internet

Turning off internet is not a option

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: In which circumstance the package API would generate network traffic? In such moment, does the package need any prerequisite trigger? My first option is to monitor network traffic generated per process. If the network traffic is too much, try to cut them in smaller pieces that could be isolated into package based traffic.

Comment: Are you concerned with malicious intent...that is, some module doing something it shouldn't do, like sending your private data elsewhere?

Comment: @steve I am using ubutu 16.04. yes my worry is that package owners are collecting data which i feel is not wrong ,but in my case i am not suppose to send any data out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the universal solution on `Unix` you could use [`strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) utlity. Example for script:

```
# req.py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
```

Run via strace: `strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 python req.py`

```
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("3.211.1.78")}, 16) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, [1], [4]) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(43484), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.88.201")}, [128->16]) = 0
...
```